# what are the eigenvalues of $X^TAX$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Say I know that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, what would be the eigenvalue of the matrix $X^TAX$?

Comment: I don't think $\lambda$ has any relation to any eigenvalue of $X^\top A X$, in general.

Comment: @TheoBendit or may extracting a bound on the eigenvalue of the multiplication is term of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $X$, could that be done?

Comment: You need to edit this detail into your question, because this makes it substantially more general and more complex. You should also include your efforts to solve the problem for yourself, because questions that simply state a problem tend to be closed (your question has one close vote already; only four more are needed).

Comment: What is known about $X$? For example, if it is an orthogonal matrix then the eigenvalue of $X^TAX^{-1}$ is equal to the eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: If $A$ is real symmetric and $X$ is real and nonsingular, then $X^TAX$ possesses an eigenvalue with the same sign as $\lambda$, by Sylvester's law of inertia.